# No funciona el action de formulario PHP POST

Tags: php, html, post

Estoy realizando un **login** basico y quiero validar la funcion de sesiones que tiene `php` pero al momento de dar **login** la página se queda cargando y es como si no recononiera el action del `form`, dejo mi código, no sé si estoy haciendo algo mal.

Este es el formulario, como ven este es el `action` y método por cual `php` se supone va recibir la informacion

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <meta name="description" content="Diseño y Desarrollo web">
      <meta name="keywords" content="diseño web, desarrollo web, seo, posicionamiento web">
    <meta name="author" content="Render2Web">
    <title>SharTorrent</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/esiloslogin.css">

  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <div class="contenedor">
        <div id="marca">
        <h1><span class="resaltado">Shar</span>Torrent</h1>
        </div>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li class="actual"><a href="index.html">Inicio</a></li>
            <li class="actual"><a href="Juegos.html">Juegos</a></li>
            <li class="actual" ><a href="contacto.html">contacto</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
    <div class="login-page">
       <form action="validar.php" method="post" >
          <input name="usuario" id="usuario" type="text" placeholder="username"/>
          <input name="pass" id="pass" type="password" placeholder="password"/>
          <input type="submit" value="enviar" />
          <p class="message">No tienes una cuenta? <a href="#">Solicitala</a></p>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>

    <footer>
      <p>SharTorrent</p>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Después de que se envía se supone que debería hacer esto, validar en el `php` que deberia tomar la informacion del formulario pero simplemente en la pantalla de `login.html` se queda cargando como si no hiciera esto o como si algo estuviera mal cuando entro al validar.php directamente si hace la funcion y me tira error por que claramente las variables del usuario y la contraseña estan vacias por lo tanto no va a encontrar nada

```php
<?php
$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
$contra = $_POST['pass'];
//conecto ala base de datos
// $mysqli = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', '');
$conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","shartorrent");
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM usu WHERE nombre='$usuario'and pass ='$contra'";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);


$filas =mysqli_num_rows($resultado);


if ($filas > 0) {
  session_start();
  //recibir el usuario
  $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
  header("Location:Registrar.php");

} else {
echo "error";
}

mysqli_free_result($resultado);
mysqli_close($conexion);


 ?>
```

Lo he probado en `xampp` y `wammp` pero hace exactamente lo mismo, de antemano muchas gracias!

esta es la pagina Registrar.php

```php
<?php
session_start();
 $varsesion = $_SESSION['usuario'];
 if($varsesion == null || $varsesion == ""){
   echo "hay que cambiarlo";
   die(); 
}
 ?>


<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Shar register</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto|Varela+Round|Open+Sans">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">

</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="contenedor">
      <div id="marca">
      <h1><span class="resaltado">Shar</span>Torrent</h1>
      </div>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li class="actual"><a href="index.html">Inicio</a></li>
          <li class="actual"><a href="Juegos.html">Juegos</a></li>
          <li class="actual" ><a href="contacto.html">contacto</a></li>
              <li class="actual" ><a href="cerrarsesion.php">Cerrar Sesion</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
     <div class="container">
        <div class="table-wrapper">
            <div class="table-title">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-8"><h2>Agregar <b>juego</b></h2></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <!-- <a href="index.php" class="btn btn-info add-new"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i> Regresar</a> -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <form method="post">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <label>Nombre del juego:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" class='form-control'  required >
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <label>link:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="link" id="apellidos" class='form-control'  required>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <label>descripcion:</label>
                    <textarea  name="descripcion" id="descripcion" class='form-control' required></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <label>Teléfono:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="peso" id="peso" class='form-control'  required>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <label>Usuario:</label>
                    <input type="text" disabled value="<?php $varsesion ?>" name="usu" id="usu" class='form-control'required>

                </div>

                <div class="col-md-12 pull-right">
                <hr>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Guardar datos</button>
                </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Eso que estás mostrando es muy inseguro. Imagínate que al input `pass` le pongo: `"asdf'; drop table usu;--"`. Tu sentencia queda `"SELECT * FROM usu WHERE nombre='$usuario'and pass ='asdf';drop table usu; --'"`. Debieras usar sentencias preparadas y de paso no guardar la contraseña en texto plano. Dicho esto, podrías poner el código de `Registrar.php`?

Comment: @amenadi acabe de actualizar la pregunta lo de pasar las contraseñas de esa manera lo hago por que es un ejercicio simple pero lo que me importaria saber es por que al enviar la informacion no hace nada

Answer (score 1):

No reconozco algún error específico, yo te recomendaria ir por pasos,

- Primero dejar solo el código necesario para realizar el post,
- En este caso el formulario y en el archivo validar.php solo las variables que estas recibiendo
- Después de realizar la prueba si todo funciona, empieza a agregar el codigo restante y probando mientras lo haces.

Debe ser algo que no tiene nada que ver con el formulario.